# Use of undeclared identifier 'cell' in TableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I don't understand why I've got this message, and how to fix it.

In my below code, every line containing "cell" gives me a message "Use of undeclared identifier 'cell'"...

```
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LocationCell"; 
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     (LocationsTableViewCellController *)cell = (LocationsTableViewCellController *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

      Feed *feed = [_feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

      cell.phraseLabel.text = feed.title;
      //cell.detailTextLabel.text = new.place;
      //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"location.png"];

      return cell;
  }

  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section                 {
    return [_feeds count];
    }
```

Comment: What you are doing in your first line is typecasting your `cell` to `LocationsTableViewCellController ` instead of declaring it. Use `LocationsTableViewCellController * cell =`. Also if you are using `dequeue`, you might want to add a `cell == nil` condition just to be sure. Will *possibly* crash at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LocationsTableViewCellController *cell = (LocationsTableViewCellController *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Don't need brackets.